# Не работает код pyqt5 как надо

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, keypressevent

У меня есть код. В котором я хочу сделать функцию. При нажатии кнопки `open1` добавляется в `gridlayout` виджет и фон заблюривается.

Так же и со второй кнопкой, только открывается уже другой виджет. Я хочу сделать так, что при нажатии `open1` открывался виджет, в котором я смогу нажать **`ESC`** и он закроется и блур пропадет. Так же и со вторым окном.

Но почему-то у меня в коде блур пропадает, но виджет из `gridlayout` не закрывается. Как это можно исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow3(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 140)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 301, 71))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 4);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Red label"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))

class ExampleApp3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.r)

    def r(self):
        self.close()


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 140)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 301, 71))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(57, 110, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blue label"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.d)

    def d(self):
        self.close()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 211, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 301, 71))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(128, 255, 10);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 200, 211, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Green label"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open2"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.un)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.un2)
    
    def un(self):

        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2()   
        self.exampleApp.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clickedApp2) 
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()

        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp, 0, 0, 2, 1)  

        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)   

        self.effectFlag = True
        self.update() 

    def un2(self):

        self.exampleApp_3 = ExampleApp3()   
        self.exampleApp_3.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedApp3) 
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()

        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp_3, 0, 0, 2, 1)  

        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)   

        self.effectFlag = True
        self.update() 

    def clickedApp2(self):
        self.exampleApp.close()
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   

        self.effectFlag = False
        self.update() 


    def clickedApp3(self):
        self.exampleApp_3.close()
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   

        self.effectFlag = False
        self.update() 

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key()  == Qt.Key_Escape :
            self.exampleApp = ExampleApp3()  
            self.exampleApp.close()
            self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
            self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
            self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
            self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
            self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
            self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   

            self.effectFlag = False
            self.update() 

    def keyPressEvent2(self, e):
        if e.key()  == Qt.Key_Escape :
            self.exampleApp_3 = ExampleApp3()  
            self.exampleApp_3.close()
            self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
            self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
            self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
            self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
            self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
            self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   

            self.effectFlag = False
            self.update() 



if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не совсем понимаю, что у вас происходит. Поэтому не вникая в логику, я сделал некоторые исправления и отметил их. Проверьте - это то что вы хотели?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow3(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 140)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 301, 71))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 4);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Red label"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))


class ExampleApp3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#?        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.r)
#?    def r(self):
#?        self.close()


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 140)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 301, 71))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(57, 110, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blue label"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#?        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.d)
#?    def d(self):
#?        print("ExampleApp2 def d(self):")
#?        self.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(463, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 211, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 301, 71))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(128, 255, 10);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 200, 211, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Green label"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open2"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.un)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.un2)

        self.exampleApp_2, self.exampleApp_3 = None, None                 # +++


    def un(self):  
# ?        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2()
        self.exampleApp_2 = ExampleApp2()                                 # exampleApp_2
        self.exampleApp_2.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clickedApp2) 
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp_2, 0, 0, 2, 1)  
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)   
        self.effectFlag = True
        self.update() 

    def un2(self):
        self.exampleApp_3 = ExampleApp3()   
        self.exampleApp_3.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedApp3) 
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp_3, 0, 0, 2, 1)  
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(3)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)   
        self.effectFlag = True
        self.update() 

    def clickedApp2(self):
        self.exampleApp_2.close()
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   
        self.effectFlag = False
        self.update() 

    def clickedApp3(self):
        self.exampleApp_3.close()
        self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
        self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
        self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
        self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
        self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
        self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   
        self.effectFlag = False
        self.update() 

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key()  == Qt.Key_Escape :

            if self.exampleApp_2: self.clickedApp2()                      # +++
            if self.exampleApp_3: self.clickedApp3()                      # +++

            '''
            self.exampleApp = ExampleApp3()  
            self.exampleApp.close()
            self.effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  
            self.effect.setBlurRadius(0)
            self.pushButton.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)  
            self.effect2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect2.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect2)
            self.effect3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect() 
            self.effect3.setBlurRadius(0)        
            self.pushButton_2.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect3)

            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)   
            self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)   

            self.effectFlag = False
            self.update() 
            '''


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```